# send ios phone push notification to mountain lion desktop too

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I assume the answer is no, but was asked if it is possible to have a push notification I send to a phone via push notification also show up in the mt lion notification center?

Comment: I would assume yes. You just have to take the same push notification payload and send it to Apple with a different device token.

Comment: But the device token comes when you install an app.  If you dont have a mountain lion app to install then you would have no way to get the device token for the desktop.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have an app for OS X, there is no way to send it a push notification. Also, you cannot link iOS and OS X in this way. There is no way to send an iPhone a push notification and have the same exact one appear on a Mac.